# How to sort date with 'MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a' in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sort JavaScript Object Array By Date (mm/DD/yyyy hh/mm/ss Am/Pm)

```
var array = [
  { id: 1, date: Mar 12 2017   10:00:00 AM }, 
  { id: 2 ,date: Mar 12 2017   08:00:00 PM },
  { id: 3, date: Mar 12 2017   05:00:00 AM },
  { id: 4, date: Mar 18 2017   09:00:00 AM }
];

Here is my logic:-
sortedPatients = PatientsListArray.sort((a, b) =>
            b.Date.split('/')
              .reverse()
              .join()
              .localeCompare(
                a.Date.split('/')
                  .reverse()
                  .join()
              )
          )
```

Got output like this  `id4 , id1 , id2 , id3`

Expected output like this `id4, id2, id3, id1`

Answer (score 2):

```js
const array = [
  {id: 1, date: 'Mar 12 2017   10:00:00 AM'},
  {id: 2, date: 'Mar 12 2017   08:00:00 PM'},
  {id: 3, date: 'Mar 12 2017   05:00:00 AM'},
  {id: 4, date: 'Mar 18 2017   09:00:00 AM'},
];

console.log(
  array.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date))
);
```

With this callback function in the `sort` method you get the order of id4, id2, id1 and id3. I don't understand why you'd like to get the order id4, id2, *id3 and id1*.

If you want a reversed order, just swap the positions of `b` and `a` so that you have `(a, b) => new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date)`.

If you already have `Date` objects (looks like it as you have used `b.Date` and `a.Date` in your code), you could write something like this:

```
sortedPatients = PatientsListArray.sort((a, b) => b.Date - a.Date))
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply, it's working for me